# Best way to replicate servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, imaging

I currently have two servers both with linux software RAID1 configurations. They use heartbeat and DRBD to create a shared DRBD device that hosts a a exported NFS directory. The servers run Ubuntu Server with a LXDE GUI and some IP

These servers are going to be placed on fishing vessels to act has redundant storage for IP cameras.

My boss wants me to figure out the most efficient way to create these servers. We might be looking at pushing out several systems a week. Each configuration will be almost identical besides IP addressing.

What would be the best method to automate the configuration process? We are trying to cut down on labor costs to set these up. Imaging and Proceeding are both on my mind right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each configuration will be almost identical besides IP addressing.

If that's the only thing that will be different, image the systems and then change the address with a script that mounts the filesystem, and edits the network configuration file.

For good measure changes the partition UUIDs and associated fstab entries, and if they exist any ssh host keys (I'd suggest deleting the host keys from the image master to force regeneration).

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/156063/why-cant-mint-boot-my-cloned-ubuntu-partition-uuid-issue for reference.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. What is the best way to go about imaging software RAID 1?